# Jest : waiting for an event to process test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, discord.js

I am coding a Discord bot and I want to test some code. With the discord.js library, we have to use a client to connect to the Discord API. At the beginning the client receives an event when it's ready:

In my `index.js`

```js
client.on('ready', () => {})
```

But in my test I need information (a guild) coming from the cache of the client:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  client.on('ready',  () => {
    // => guild that I need for test
    guildToTest =  client.guilds.cache.get('912785389704609832');
  });
});

describe('setCounterForRoles testing', () => {
  test('Unit test', async () => {
    // => Here guildToTest is null
    const guilds = await setCounterForRoles(guildToTest);
  });
});
```

I need the guild for the test but this test is processed before the event `ready` is coming so the `guild` is `null`.

How can I make sure that the `ready` event is fired before running the tests?

I read some things in the docs on `jest.spyOn()` but I don't know if it's the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run tests on a live Discord server, you can connect to the Discord server and get the guild inside `beforeAll()`. Your problem is that `client.on` is asynchronous, so you need to tell Jest that you're connected to the server and got the guild.

If the function passed to `beforeAll()`returns a promise, Jest waits for that promise to resolve before running your tests. So, you can return a promise here and resolve it inside your callback function.

Also, make sure you terminate the connection to Discord using the [`destroy()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=destroy) method inside your `afterAll()`. If you don't do this, Jest will complain that it *"did not exit one second after the test run has completed"*.

```js
let guildID = '912785389704609832';
let guild;

beforeAll(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    client.on('ready', async () => {
      guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID);

      resolve();
    });
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  client.destroy();
});

describe('Connect to Discord', () => {
  test('get the guild by its ID', async () => {
    expect(guild.id).toBe(guildID);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Last question: why do you fetch the guild and you don't get it in the cache ? If the client is ready, the cache is updated ?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm using `fetch()` for two reasons. First, to show you how to work with asynchronous functions and second, because `fetch()` still returns the cached guild if it's already available. It only fetches the guild from Discord if it's not cached yet. [There are cases](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discordjs/comments/r2ephd/clientguilds_always_returns_an_empty_guildmanager/) when the server is not cached and `cache.get(ID)` returns `undefined`. `fetch()` is just "safer" :)